# Instantiate new object on index page in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instantiation, nomethoderror

simple question that I am not able to solve some how.

I am trying to mimic the first few steps of this [Railscast Episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/381-jquery-file-upload). I have a `picture`-Model and I am trying to instantiate an object of this kind on the index page. Therefor I am using those lines:

**index.erb.html**

```
<%= form_for Picture.new do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :image, "Upload" %>
    <%= f.file_field :image, multiple: true %>
<% end %>
```

But I am getting this error:

```
undefined method `pictures_path' for #<#<Class:0xb465af0>:0x58fc488>
```

If I remove the form it works perfectly. Seems simple but I can't solve it. I would appreciate some help.

**PicturesController**

```
class PicturesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html

  def index
    @house = House.find(params[:house_id])
    @pictures = @house.pictures
    respond_with(@pictures)
  end

  def new
    @picture = Picture.new
  end

  def create
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private

  def picture_params
    params.require(:picture).permit(:id, :name, :house_id, :image, :_destroy)
  end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :houses do
      resources :pictures, only: [:index]
  end
end
```

Comment: could you show your full view code: `index.html.erb`?

Comment: Also your routes.rb please.

Comment: It's actually both in there but maybe in a bad format. I will fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your given routes info, you don't really have `pictures_path`. You have only these routes (if you do a `rake routes`):

```
house_pictures GET    /houses/:house_id/pictures(.:format) pictures#index
        houses GET    /houses(.:format)                    houses#index
```

That's why you are getting that error.

You have access to `house_pictures_path` BUT NOT `pictures_path`.

To solve this issue, you have to use `house_pictures_path` and send the `@house` and `@pictures` as argument to that. something like this:

```
<%= form_for [@house, @house.pictures.build] do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :image, "Upload" %>
    <%= f.file_field :image, multiple: true %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yes, that's it of course :D Thanks for opening my eyes again. Although it has to be `@house.pictures.build` since its one-to-many association. If you change that in your answer I am happy to accept it as solving answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer. But, did you try `@house.pictures.new` actually? that should work too as it has a `has_many` association with the picture, so `@house.pictures.new` and `@house.pictures.build` should have the same effect. See this for reference: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L124

Comment: Yea, you're right. You wrote `@house.picture.new` in your first answer but I should have seen that the missing "s" was the problem and not the method. So both would be correct aslong as its plural. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `pictures` resource is nested within your `houses` resource. There is no route to allow you to create a new `Picture` without a `House` to provide the surrounding context, and so `form_for` cannot automatically produce a URL if you give it *only* `Picture.new`.

You need to give it both a house, and a picture.

Typically, your would do something like this:

```
form_for [@house, @house.pictures.new] do |f|
```